# jQuery sliding animation inside a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm toying around with jQuery/jQuery-ui, and I'd like to do something : say we have a word, when I hover the first letter, I'd like to see a few letters slide in (and out when the mouse goes somewhere else) between the first letter and the rest of the word. So FSecond would become FirstSecond, with "irst" sliding.

I'm almost there, but there's a slight problem : the sliding letters are sliding below the word, and once the sliding is done, they are at the right place. Same thing for the sliding out : the animation itself is not taking place between the first letter and the rest of the word.

Here is the code, quite short : http://pastebin.com/FdTtmV7k. I checked the jquery-ui doc and there's a mention of an options hash to give to the toggle function, but I can't seem to find any doc on this one and what to put in it.

I also noticed a few similar questions left unanswered (see [jQuery slideToggle() applies display:block while sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996318/jquery-slidetoggle-applies-displayblock-while-sliding) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090796/jquery-ui-show-moves-elements-during-animation).

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**This demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lct4U/10/) should do what you require. The problem exists as jQuery assigns `display:block` to an element when animating it, which causes your `<span>` to be rendered as a [block-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3).

Comment: The problem is that jQuery wraps your element in a `div` when animating it, not that it assigns `display:block`. Check it out in a debugger

Comment: @josh.trow my demo does not use jQueryUI. I am not sure how it can add the `ui-effects-wrapper`. I totally accept that this might happen but I just can't see it at the moment! **Edit** Sorry was not loading jQueryUI when looking for this. I see it being wrapped in a `<div>` when using jQueryUI but my demo does not need that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really look at your source code, I was just working off of what I saw from the pastebin code that Katen provided. I do see that yours works as expected though.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. This is exactly how I want it to work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the `<span>` containing the `"irst"` text will have the CSS `display` property changed to `block` when the sliding begins, while the other 2 `<span>` elements used for `"F"` and `"Second"` will keep their default, which is inline.

You can solve this by changing the `<span>` elements to `<div>` elements (these are block elements) and additionally apply `float: left;` CSS style to them.

The new HTML code:

```html
<h3>
    <div id="initial">F</div><div id="middle" style="display: none">irst</div><div id="name">Second</div>
</h3>
```

And the new CSS code:

```css
#initial, #middle, #name { float: left; }
```

Comment: You can also keep the current `<span>` elements and just apply a `display: block;` property on them ... it's up to you.

Comment: If you look at debugger tools, it actually temporarily wraps the element (span tag) in a `div` with class `ui-effects-wrapper`

Comment: @josh.trow yes, you are right. Just checked it and it looks like the `span` is getting the `inline` display style.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this CSS fixed it for me. The reasoning is that jQuery wraps your `span` in a `div` while animating it, and that `div` has `display:block` by default. We take advantage of the fact that they did not set an inline `display` style on the element and set the class to have `display:inline-block`.

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

EDIT: Something was messing up my `span` tags, no margin modifications are needed.